# How to group by in SQL by largest date (Order By a Group By)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I have the following database table

[image]

Here is my sample data I have for it.

[image]

What I am trying to figure out how to do is how to write a query to select all apntoken for userid='20' grouping by deviceid and then by apntoken as well (except that it should show the most recent apntoken).

**Some queries I have tried are this.**

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT apntoken,deviceid,created 
FROM `distribution_mobiletokens` 
WHERE userid='20' 
GROUP BY deviceid
```

This returns the following result.

[image]

Notice the date is not the newest date.  I added a fake entry called 'latestone' for apntoken where I set its date into the future.

Another query I tried is this.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT apntoken,deviceid,created 
FROM `distribution_mobiletokens` 
WHERE userid='20' 
GROUP BY deviceid,apntoken
```

Problem with this one however is I have extra data for the deviceid now since its not unique anymore?

Refer to picture

[image]

I'm not sure how to modify this query to do this or if this is easily possible?

For example I should with the data I have get back only '2' fields.  One for deviceid 5628CF60-D0CF-479A-A944-A3496E085FC8 & 948D9BAD-B164-4830-ACEB-08A089A80558 like in the picture for the first query I tried but it should show the apntoken that says 'latestone'

The reason I need this is so I always send the 'newest' tokens to apple for push notifications for a particular device.  Everytime a user logs in the device is the same but the apntoken can be different.  So I figured if I can take the newest apntoken from the device for a user this will do the trick.

OTHER Queries I've tried

```
SELECT apntoken,deviceid,created 
FROM `distribution_mobiletokens` 
WHERE userid='20' 
GROUP BY deviceid ORDER BY created DESC
```

[image]

Notice it does not show latestone which should show up with its date

Comment: GROUP BY deviceid, apntoken, ...

Comment: I forgot to put that I tried that but that won't work for me will edit question

Comment: The group by is used  for aggregation function as  min ,  count .. i don't see any aggregation function in your query  .. if you need  unique rows you can use distinct ..(but distinct and group by have no sense)

Comment: I recently modified question to make it more clear, let me know if that helps at all, basically I need to somehow do an Order By on a Group By for deviceid, where it orders the grouping by createdDate newest

Comment: how about order by created desc

Comment: good idea, I tried SELECT 
   DISTINCT apntoken,deviceid,created 
FROM `distribution_mobiletokens` 
WHERE userid='20' 
GROUP BY deviceid ORDER BY created ASC, and DESC variation but returned same result

Comment: I modified question to show results when I tried orderby, still no luck

Comment: I think this should work GROUP BY deviceid,created ORDER BY created DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite way to construct this SQL is to use a `not exists` clause like so:

```
SELECT apntoken,deviceid,created 
FROM `distribution_mobiletokens` as dm
WHERE userid='20'
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from `distribution_mobiletokens`
    where userid = '20'
    and deviceid = dm.deviceid
    and created > dm.created
    )
```

Comment: Of course :) the not exists clause is stating that any rows with the same userid (=20) and deviceid as the original table (alias dm) but having a later created date should not exist in the results of the select. Leaving only the latest rows for each userid=20 and deviceid. Voila!

Comment: search the internets for "correlated subquery"; lots of literature on it

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my question and the information, I can see I have a lot of reading to do on this subject :).

Comment: what is purpose of select 1 in this query btw?

Comment: The ```not exists``` clause looks for the existence of records, it doesn't matter what the contents of the records are. You can select a column, 1 or "blah", it doesn't matter.

Comment: I see now, so its a matter of efficiency (why select all the columns when you don't need to kind of thing), thanks!